# How do I model an array nested inside an array of objects in my data instance in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a loop displaying a list of items and sub-items. The response payload looks like this.

[image: Response payload]

I have looped successfully and I am displaying on my frontend scaffold as thus:

[image: Frontend Scaffold]

Stuck on how I would model this correctly in my data instance and still maintain the integrity of each group(A permission and sub-permissions tied to it in this case). The payload to be sent to the backend is expected as thus:

[image: Data payload to be sent]

Answer (score 0):

So Apparently, the key to 'modeling' complex structures as this is avoiding 'v-model'; as v-model is syntax sugar for 2 separate props (which vary by input)
for checkboxes, its sugar for `checked` and `@change,` for text input it's value and `@input`, etc.

This response however is somewhat tailored to the raised issue and is courtesy of  [guanzo](https://github.com/guanzo). As opposed to using v-model for the modeling or binding in this case. Functions were used to achieve this.

```
isPermissionChecked(pName) {
      return this.selected.some((p) => p.name === pName);
    },
    togglePermission(pName, event) {
      const isChecked = event.target.checked;
      if (isChecked) {
        this.selected.push({ name: pName, sub_permissions: [] });
      } else {
        const i = this.selected.findIndex((p) => p.name === pName);
        this.selected.splice(i, 1);
      }
    },
    isSubPermissionChecked(pName, spName) {
      const permission = this.selected.find((p) => p.name === pName);
      return (
        permission && permission.sub_permissions.some((sp) => sp === spName)
      );
    },
    toggleSubPermission(pName, spName, event) {
      const isChecked = event.target.checked;
      const permission = this.selected.find((p) => p.name === pName);
      if (isChecked) {
        permission.sub_permissions.push(spName);
      } else {
        const i = permission.sub_permissions.findIndex((sp) => sp === spName);
        permission.sub_permissions.splice(i, 1);
      }
    },
```

These were 'modelled' to the inputs like so:

```
<div v-for="p in permissions" :key="p.name" class="card">
        <div class="form-grop d-flex align-items-center radio-group1">
          <div class="mr-auto">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              :id="p.name"
              :checked="isPermissionChecked(p.name)"
              @change="togglePermission(p.name, $event)"
              class="mt-2"
            />
            <label :for="p.name" class="mx-2 mt-2">{{ p.name }}</label>
          </div>
          <div>
      </div>
```

and

```
   <div class="mr-auto" v-for="sp in p.sub_permissions" :key="sp">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                :id="p.name + sp"
                :disabled="!isPermissionChecked(p.name)"
                :checked="isSubPermissionChecked(p.name, sp)"
                @change="toggleSubPermission(p.name, sp, $event)"
                class="mt-2"
              />
              <label :for="p.name + sp" class="mx-2 mt-2">{{ sp }}</label>
            </div>
```